# Is it possible to recreate the same exact stats from a Pokémon team?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

I have the stats from my old Pokémon Team from Pokémon Crystal, the file was erased long ago but I took photos in case of anything.
Today I want to play the game again but recover the same stats of the Pokémon I lost.
Is it somehow possible to re-obtain the exact same stats on Pokémon Crystal (second gen)? I know there are EVs that aren't IVs, **so maybe it is possible?**

I know this is possible, but how can I calculate the exact EVs or something? I want to have them back...

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid we also need the nature. But with brute force (and a lot of handwork), you should be able to recalculate it with the aid of [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/games/iv-calcdp.shtml). Assuming all are level 100, you can try different IV and EV (I assume you meant EV instead of DV) and try to find the exact values. I also assume that the EV is maxed (you can only get a maximum amount of EV in total), so that is another constraint.

Comment: Thank you, the bad thing right here is that the Pokémon were from Gen II so the natures didn't existed yet...

Comment: Ah. But maybe the natures were just natural. So there is still a possibility :)

Comment: Natures didn't exist (hidden or otherwise) in Gens 1 or 2. Gen 3 changed the mechanics of a lot of things, including splitting the Special stats (in Gen 2 it was two base stats but they [still used the same 'Special' IV and EVs](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Stats#Special)), adding Natures, and a whole lot of other things.

Comment: @Beavoru I won't say it's impossible, if you want to get the exact same IVs and EVs it will be awfully difficult with lots of soft resetting if you ever manage to get those values correct in the first place. Bringing their final stats to what they are is another story and much easier, though their IVs and EVs might not be the same. For example, you can get an atk of 286 at Lv100 for Feraligatr if the IV is 31 and EV is 160, or if the IV is 16 and EV is 220 (and a whole bunch of other combinations that can also reach the same final value).

Comment: Thanks, i think more than just try to get them back, ill hatch them again on a remake game (HG/SS) and then see what can i do about the stats, thank you all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an emulator, there are save game editors that allow you to adjust the IVs and EVs of your Pokémon. [A Crystal to Ruby conversion tutorial](http://addictedgamewise.com/pokemon-ruby-0-5-generation-iii-save-editor/) shows one editor called Enciclopedia Pokémon that allows you to adjust these stats:

[image: Pokémon Crystal save game edit]

You can play around with the IV and EV values until you match the party you had. This probably the only way to get your team back, since it is nigh impossible to do it manually.